# R: Power analysis for a 2 by 2 within-within ANOVA interaction effect [pwr::pwr.f2.test()]

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, interaction, statistical-power

**Background**

I would like to perform a power analysis for the interaction effect in a 2 by 2 within-within ANOVA design. I would like to crosscheck that I am performing this correctly using the `pwr::pwr.f2.test()` function in R.

**Required inputs**

The `pwr::pwr.f2.test()` function requires the following parameters:

- `u`: degrees of freedom for numerator
- `v`: degrees of freedom for denominator
- `f2`: the effect size Cohen's $f^2$
- `sig.level`: $\alpha$ level
- `power`: the desired power ($1 - \beta$)

We will omit `v` so the function will estimate this value.

**Inputs for a $2 \times 2$ within-within design**

1. `u`

The numerator degrees of freedom for an interaction effect in this design is given as:

$$u = A \times B = (a - 1)(b - 1)$$

Where $a$ is the number of levels of Factor $A$, and $b$ is the number of levels of Factor $B$. Therefore, `u` is:

$$u = (2-1) \times (2-1) = 1$$

2. `f2`

Let's assume I have estimated that the interaction effect should be $\eta^2_p$ = 0.2. I can convert this to $f^2$ using the following formula:

$$f^2 = \frac{\eta^2_p}{1 - \eta^2_p}$$

Therefore, `f2` is:

$$f^2 = \frac{0.2}{1-0.2} = 0.25$$

3. `sig.level`

I will set $\alpha = .05$

4. `power`

I will set $power = 0.80$

**Perform the analysis**

We use the above inputs in the following power analysis:

```
pwr::pwr.f2.test(u = 1, f2 = 0.25, sig.level = 0.05, power = 0.8)

 Multiple regression power calculation 

          u = 1
          v = 31.42944
         f2 = 0.25
  sig.level = 0.05
      power = 0.8
```

The required denominator degrees of freedom to detect our effect with 80% power is 31.42. To convert `v` to the total $N$ required we will do some simple algebra.

The denominator degrees of freedom for a $2 \times 2$ interaction effect is given as:

$$v = A \times B \times S = (a - 1)(b - 1)(N - 1)$$

Where $N$ is the total sample size. In our study this is:

$$v = (2 - 1)(2 - 1)(N - 1) = N - 1$$

$$N = v + 1$$

This means we simply add 1 to `v` to estimate the required sample size, and round up:

```
ceiling(31.42944 + 1)
[1] 33
```

The required sample size is therefore $N = 33$.

**Question**

Have I performed these steps correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that all of the ANOVA functions in `pwr` are 1-way. If you have the right data, you should be able to do your calculation using [Superpower](https://aaroncaldwell.us/SuperpowerBook/). It's available as an [R package](https://github.com/arcaldwell49/Superpower) and a [shiny app](https://arcstats.io/shiny/anova-power/) (which is a bit like G*Power).